# Resolution too high

Tags: boot, kali-linux, display, resolution

I have kali linux running on my Macbook Pro 13"

Running cmd **xrandr** returns

```
screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1600, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 2560 x 1600
...
```

How can I get a different Resolution? **2560 x 1600** is too high.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if that would work, but try to add custom resolution to xrandr. Different driver could be selected by creating xorg.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

The option "-q" to xrandr will list all supported resolution.
You can run

```
$ xrandr -q
```

Then use one of the listed resolutions.The "-s" switch will allow you to select resolution by index (starting from 0):

```
$ xrandr -s 1
```

will select the second resolution supported.